# How to get a source code of a function in PostgreSQL including its arguments in create-or-replace format?

Tags: postgresql

I am searching for a way to display a command that creates a certain routine in PostgreSQL. I found a solution:

```
SELECT routine_definition
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_type='FUNCTION' AND specific_schema='public' AND routine_name = 'my_func'
```

That returns in my case:

```
begin
    insert into person ("name", "age") values (_name, _age)
    on conflict on constraint person_name_uk do update
    set age = _age
    where person.name = _name;
end
```

But I need the output like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.my_func(_name character varying, _age integer)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    insert into person ("name", "age") values (_name, _age)
    on conflict on constraint person_name_uk do update
    set age = _age
    where person.name = _name;
end
$function$
;
```

I have looked through the fields of `information_schema.routines` and found nothing that could help me construct the output I need. Probably, there's another place where it's stored or a standard function that I can use.

I need a solution without the slash at the beginning. I mean, anything like `\ef` doesn't fit because I can't use it inside of complex statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_get_functiondef` does exactly what you want:

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef('public.my_func'::regproc);
```

Comment: Sometimes a humble "l" makes the difference!! :-)

Comment: @coterobarros That may well be, but I have no idea how that applies to the question or the answer.

Comment: :)) I copied the select sentence, then I run into "pubic" problems! But nothing sexual

Comment: Just joking. Thank you for your continuous support

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. I read the "l" as an "I" and was left clueless.